# Integrating Authorize.net into Drupal

Tags: payment-gateways

I have a friend with a single page website that sells a single product. All he wants is an order form embedded on the one page that uses authorize.net. I can't find a single way to embed the form onto the website like I can embed a mailchimp form, for example. Do I need to set up an Advanced Integration Method to accomplish this? If I need to would it be easiest to do it though Drupal? And, what is the easiest way to do it through Drupal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hook_menu

```
items['authorize-form'] = array(

  'title' => t('Pay via Authorize'),

  'page callback' => 'generate_authorize_form',

  'access arguments' => array('access content'),

  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK

);
```

Callback function to generate authorize form using Authorize.net SDK

```
function generate_authorize_form(){
    require_once 'anet_php_sdk/AuthorizeNet.php'; // The SDK
    $url = "http://YOUR_DOMAIN.com/index.php";
    $api_login_id = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    $transaction_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $md5_setting = 'xxxxxxxxx'; // Your MD5 Setting
    $amount = "5.99";

    ob_start();
    AuthorizeNetDPM::directPostDemo($url, $api_login_id, $transaction_key, $amount, $md5_setting);

    $output = ob_get_content();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}
```